# passing a table as function parameters and values

Tags: r, data.table

Imagine I have the following function which has a lot of arguments but for the sake of simplicity I only list two here:

```r
library(glue)
glue("{a} + {b} is equal to 3", a = 1, b = 2)
```

Now I have a data.table with all the arguments/values that I want to pass to my `glue` function:
data.table:

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(varnames = c("a", "b"), values = c(1, 2))
```

How could I directly pass the arguments/values from my `DT` onto my `glue` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setNames` and call `glue_data`:

```
glue_data(setNames(DT$values, DT$varnames), "{a} + {b} is equal to 3")
#1 + 2 is equal to 3
```

or you use `do.call`:

```
do.call(glue, as.list(c("{a} + {b} is equal to 3",
    setNames(DT$values, DT$varnames))))
#1 + 2 is equal to 3
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful in this case if you had `a` and `b` as separate columns.

```
library(data.table)
library(glue)

DT_Wide <- dcast(DT, rowid(varnames)~varnames, value.var = 'values')
DT_Wide

#   varnames a b
#1:        1 1 2
```

Then you can use `glue_data` -

```
glue_data(DT_Wide, "{a} + {b} is equal to 3")

#1 + 2 is equal to 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple and use base R's `with` as this is the nice example where it is useful:

```r
library(glue)
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(varnames = c("a", "b"), values = c(1, 2))
with(
  as.list(setNames(DT$values, DT$varnames)),
  glue("{a} + {b} is equal to 3")
)
#1 + 2 is equal to 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A little hackish but gets the job done and generalises to a bigger data.frame:

```
DT <- data.table(varnames = c("a", "b", "c"), values = c(1, 2, 3))
DT[, glue_data(
       setNames(values, varnames),  
       glue_data(
         .SD,
         "{paste(sprintf('{%s}', varnames), collapse = ' + ')}", " is equal to {sum(values)}"
       )
     )]
# 1 + 2 + 3 is equal to 6
```